# MAAS error failed [3/7] (00-maas-03-install-lldpd, 99-maas-01-wait-for-lldpd, 99-maas-02-capture-lldp)

Tags: proxy, maas, pxe

The problem case:

I have two networks: one private network with a private switch, and another one connected to the internet and a proxy.

I have one MAAS Server(Ubuntu 14.0 MAAS stable version).
I want to add a node 3 physical nodes.
The nodes were added to MAAS successfully.

When I try to commission that node(with PXE boot-up), I got this error:

```
failed [3/7] (00-maas-03-install-lldpd, 99-maas-01-wait-for-lldpd, 99-maas-02-capture-lldp)
```

When I look at my log I've got the following messages :

```
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/lm-sensors/libsensors4_3.3.4-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'spike-dmz.aql.fr'    
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/perl/libperl5.18_5.18.2-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'spike-dmz.aql.fr'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/net-snmp/libsnmp-base_5.7.2~dfsg-8.1ubuntu3_all.deb  Could not resolve 'spike-dmz.aql.fr'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/net-snmp/libsnmp30_5.7.2~dfsg-8.1ubuntu3_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'spike-dmz.aql.fr'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/l/lldpd/lldpd_0.7.7-1_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'spike-dmz.aql.fr'
```

`spike-dmz.aql.fr` is my proxy.

And I have other problem but I think proxy is my main problem.

What do I have to do to resolve my problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Worked out by using own ["commissioning script"](https://github.com/Yadro-Intra/utilities/blob/master/00-aaaa-maas-intra-diag.sh#L135) to install `lldpd` among other things.

This boils down to this command:

```
apt-get install -y --force-yes --allow-unauthenticated lldpd
```

Answer (score 0):

the 3 nodes fail in the same manner while being comissioned. 
So when you used a proxy and 2 NIC on your Maas Server you HAVE TO set iptables rules !!
For me it was:

eth0 internet eth1 private network

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

and after that My nodes was able to have  "Node changed status — From 'Commissioning' to 'Ready'"